# How to use the entered point as the top of cone instead of base of cone?

Tags: vba, autocad

I've written the following code to create a solid cone and the cone center that I enter is a base point, but I need to use the entered point as the top of the cone.

Which part of the code should I change?

```vb
Public Sub Drawcone()
    Dim coneobject As Acad3DSolid
    Dim cinecenter As Variant
    Dim coneradius As Double
    Dim coneheight As Double
    With ThisDrawing.Utility
        conecenter = .GetPoint(, vbCr & "select position for base of cone:")
        coneradius = .GetDistance(conecenter, vbCr & "Enter radius of base :")
        coneheight = .GetDistance(conecenter, vbCr & "enter geight of cone:")
    End With
    conecenter(2) = conecenter(2) + coneheight / 2#
    Set cneobject = ThisDrawing.ModelSpace.AddCone(conecenter, coneradius, coneheight)
    coneobject.Update
    ChangeViewDirection
End Sub
```

[Reference Link](http://what-when-how.com/autocad-vba/creating-3d-solids-creating-and-drawing-3d-solids-autocad-vba-part-3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```vb
conecenter(2) = conecenter(2) + coneheight / 2#
```

to:

```vb
conecenter(2) = conecenter(2) - coneheight / 2#
```

That is, the cone center (the center of the bounding box of the cone) required by the `addcone` method is a point with z-coordinate half the cone height below the top of the cone.